# jQuery - Get value of .NET RequiredFieldValidator "ControlToValidate"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple function that will loop through all requiredfield elements with the ".err" class. When I catch such an element I want to add some css classes to its associated ControlToValidate. However, I keep getting "undefined" as a result.
Below is a sample:

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbx" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="err" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbx" />
```

js

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $(".err").each(function (j) {
        if ($(this).css("visibility") !== "hidden") {
            console.log($(this).attr("ControlToValidate")); //produces undefined
            console.log($(this).attr("id"); //logs correct id
        }
    });
});
```

I have also tried `val.("ControlToValidate")` which produced undefined as well.

I feel like the solution is right under my nose. Please help!

Comment: If you look at the rendered html on your page, my guess would be that there is no `ControlToValidate` property.

Comment: @RickS you're right, that attribute isn't showing up in the DOM. Do you have a suggestion for a workaround? Name my TxtBx and Validator to similar id's perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could name the RequiredFieldValidator and append the name of the TextBox to it.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_txtbx" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="err" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbx" />
```

Or you could look into Microsoft's page validators which should give you access to controltovalidate : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx